# Limiting Size of a particular queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way to limit size of a queue in ActiveMQ. Like I have four queues: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 and I want when Q3 has 200 MB of messages it should block untill messages are not consumed, but other Q1, Q2, Q4 function normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but you have to do it in steps.

There are different types of memory, like normal memory "RAM" or disk space in the persistent store. You have to configure them separately. Since when the "RAM" memory is out, the message is swapped out and fetched from store (depending a bit on the configuration).

However, you have hopefully a system wide limit, like this:

```
  <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>
```

Given these entries as a starting point, you can apply [per-destination-policies](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html) that limit certain queue(s). That is set as a percentage of the system memory, so you need to do some calculations. 
Use `storeUsageHighWaterMark` and/or `cursorMemoryHighWaterMark` depending on the effect you want. Note that store is not used for non persistent messages.

For a basic memory limit, you can also use the `memoryLimit` setting on the destination policy. It's a child to the `memoryUsage` system property.

Comment: isn't this on a broker level? as supposed to queue level?
so it will be applicable to all the queues,not some particular queue

Comment: Those are per destination policy settings, so you typically setup a policy like `<policyEntry queue="ORDERS.>">` to make it cover all queues starting with ORDERS etc. Then apply the memory restrictions for this queue (or set of queues).

Comment: ohh..then it works..maybe tweaking the naming convention will be needed to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

```
<policyEntry queue="ANOTHER.>" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="12 kb">
```

not limiting the queue size to 12 kb

Comment: You should edit your previous post instead of posting essentially the same thing again.